# Formula for $T_k(x + 1)$ where $T_k$ is $k$-th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Let $T_k(x)$ be the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind of order $k$, i.e., the polynomial given by the recurrence relation
\begin{align}
T_0(x)=1, \quad T_1(x)=x, \quad T_k(x)=2xT_{k-1}(x)-T_{k-2}(x), \quad k =2, 3,\ldots
\end{align} I'm looking for a formula that gives $T_k(x+1)$ as a linear combination of $T_j(x)$ for $j=0,1,\ldots,k$. For $k= 0, 1, \ldots, 5$ I computed
\begin{align}
T_0(x+1)&=T_0(x), \\
T_1(x+1)&=T_1(x) + T_0(x), \\
T_2(x+1)&=T_2(x) + 4T_1(x) + 2T_0(x), \\
T_3(x+1)&=T_3(x) + 6T_2(x) + 12T_1(x) + 7T_0(x), \\
T_4(x+1)&=T_4(x) + 8T_3(x) + 24T_2(x) + 40T_1(x)+ 24T_0(x),\\
T_5(x+1)&=T_5(x) + 10T_4(x) + 40T_3(x) + 90T_2(x) + 140 T_1(x) + 81 T_0(x).
\end{align}
These results are found simplifying the explicit formulas for the Chebyshev polynomials. I don't find a clear pattern here.

My goal, denoting by $\mathbf{T}_K(x)=(T_0(x),T_1(x),\cdots,T_K(x))^\top\in \mathbb{R}^K$, would be to find the matrix $M_K \in \mathbb R^{K\times K}$ such that $\mathbf T_K(x+1) = M_K \mathbf T_K(x)$ without having to compute "manually" the coefficients for any arbitrary $K$.

Comment: Is it only a typo or is it the basis of all of your calculations? The formula must be $T_k(x) = 2xT_{k-1}(x)-T_{k-2}(x)$

Comment: It's a typo, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious approach would be to try to convert the calculations that you did into "matrix-notation". That would result into something like the following. Let $A_K$ be the $(K+1)\times (K+1)$-matrix with the coefficients of the Chebyshev polynomials up to degree $K$ of the first kind:
$$
A_K =
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  0 &    &    &    & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 &  1 &  0 &    &    &        &  \\
-1 &  0 &  2 &  0 &    &        &  \\
 0 & -3 &  0 &  4 &  0 &        & \vdots \\
 1 &  0 & -8 &  0 &  8 & \ddots &  \\
\vdots &  &  &    &    & \ddots & 0 \\
\vdots &  &  &    &    &        & 2^{K-1} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $B_K$ the matrix with the binomial coefficients $\binom{i}{j}$ in the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column:
$$
B_K =
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  0 &    &    &    & \cdots & 0 \\
 1 &  1 &  0 &    &    &        &  \\
 1 &  2 &  1 &  0 &    &        &  \\
 1 &  3 &  3 &  1 &  0 &        & \vdots \\
 1 &  4 &  6 &  4 &  1 & \ddots &  \\
\vdots &  &  &    &    & \ddots & 0 \\
 1 &   &  &    &    &        & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then
$$ 
M_K = A_K B_K A_K^{-1}
$$
I have taken a look at a few of the $A_K^{-1}$ and it seems that the rows are independent of $K,$ that is, for larger $K$, you do not have to recalculate all the rows that you have already calculated for smaller values of $K$. However, I have not found a proof for that fact, and I have not found an elegant way of computing the rows of $A_K^{-1},$ either. When I come up with something, I will extend this answer accordingly.